# looking for iptables example

Tags: linux, iptables

May I have an example of an bash script that uses iptables to only allow access to two websites ?

I want to use it in order to have a whitelist locally and restrict my access to the web to a limited set of places.

I want to run this on my workstation(my desktop computer)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't typically do this with iptables you would use something like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) proxy with a suitable acl e.g.

```
acl OKSites dstdomain "/usr/local/etc/allowed-sites.squid"

#
# Add this at the top of the http_access section of squid.conf
#
http_access allow OKSites
http_access deny all
```

Where the allowed-sites.squid file contains a list of allowed sites

```
google.com
oterhdomain.co.uk
```

If you really must do this with iptables then

```
# deny everything
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

# Allow DNS
iptables -I OUPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d serverfault.com --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d stackoverflow.com --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

would allow access to DNS. Be aware that, using this method the IP address of the site is only updated when the rule is added to the filter. If the IP address of the site changes then access will be enabled agai so you'd need to reload the rules.

Comment: does it make sense to have a squid locally on my workstation ?

Comment: I tried the method you indicated with iptables, and it works ! Thank you ! But It seems if I rerun it, and try to access serverfault.com from chrome, the request just .. lags, so blank screen and still loading. if I curl serverfault.com it works on the commandline but the browser doesn't want to load the page. if I do /etc/init.d/networking restart while the page is loading, the page loads in chrome also.. but that's just for one page, I can't do that each time..